# React: how to initialise redux state before rendering component?

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm trying to create a basic app with a user login feature using Redux to manage the user details. I've linked a GIF of my screen below and, as you can see, there is a delay between loading the component and the user details rendering. My code for the component profile is also noted.

[Name of user delay when loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5EQd.gif)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchProfile} from '../../actions/ProfileActions';
import {logoutUser} from '../../actions/AuthActions';

class Profile extends Component {
  state = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    goals: '',
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchProfile();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps !== this.props) {
      this.setState({
        firstName: this.props.profile.firstName,
        lastName: this.props.profile.lastName,
        email: this.props.profile.email,
        goals: this.props.profile.goals,
      });
    }
  }

  onPressLogout = () => {
    this.props.logoutUser();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.header}>
            Profile of {this.state.firstName} {this.state.lastName}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.textContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.buttonContainer}
            onPress={this.onPressLogout.bind(this)}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Logout</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  profile: state.profile.profile,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchProfile, logoutUser})(Profile);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F9F9F9',
  },
  headerContainer: {
    marginTop: 75,
    marginLeft: 20,
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 34,
    fontWeight: '700',
    color: '#000000',
  },
  textContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 30,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#34495E',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 12,
    width: 350,
    borderRadius: 15,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 19,
  },
});
```

EDIT: I forgot to explain what `fetchProfile()` does. It connects to the firebase database to retrieve the user's details. Code below:

```
import {PROFILE_FETCH} from './types';
import firebase from 'firebase';

export const fetchProfile = () => {
  const {currentUser} = firebase.auth();

  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/profile`)
      .on('value', (snapshot) => {
        dispatch({
          type: PROFILE_FETCH,
          payload: snapshot.val(),
        });
      });
  };
};
```

Furthermore, I have 3 different screens in the app, all of which will probably make use of the user's details. I'm sure there must be a more efficient way of only having to `fetchProfile()` once and then passing the details to each component, somehow...

How can I have it so when the user logs in, their details are already loaded in the component, so there is no delay? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain what fetchProfile does in this scenario? Does it fetch details from an API? Better if you can post code parts of that as well.

Comment: Totally forgot to mention it, I've updated the question with its code.

Answer (score 0):

One way I've gotten around this is by conditionally rendering a [skeleton](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/04/skeleton-screens-react/) if it is still loading and then actually rendering the details once finished. 
I'm not sure if this is exactly the solution you're looking for (and you may already know it's an option), but maybe this helps?

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I will probably just do this if I can't find another way to get around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you have provided, definitely there will be a delay. I'll explain what is happening here.

You are requesting data from the firebase after you have rendered the details on Profile. This happens because you are requesting data in componentDidMount method. This method gets called first time Render method is completely finished rendering your components. So I'll suggest you two methods to get rid of that.

1. As Coding Duck suggested, you can show a skeleton loader until you fetch data from the firebase.
2. You can request these data from your login. That means, if user authentication is success, you can request these data using `fetchProfile` action and once you fetch these data completely, you can use `Navigation.navigate('Profile')` to navigate to your Profile screen rather than directly navigate to it once the authentication is success. In that time since you have fetched data already, there will be no issue.

Also you can use firebase persist option to locally store these data. So even if there were no internet connection, still firebase will provide your profile information rapidly.

**EDIT**

More specific answer with some random class and function names. This is just an example.

Let's say onLogin function handles all your login requirements in your authentication class.

```
onLogin = () => {
  /** Do the validation and let's assume validation is success */
  /** Now you are not directly navigating to your Profile page like you did in the GIF. I assume that's what you did because you have not added more code samples to fully understand what you have done.*/
  /** So now you are calling the fetchProfile action through props and retrieve your details. */
  this.props.fetchProfile(this.props.navigation);
};
```

Now let's modify your fetchDetails action.

```
export const fetchProfile = (navigation) => {
  const {currentUser} = firebase.auth();

  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/profile`)
      .on('value', (snapshot) => {
        dispatch({
          type: PROFILE_FETCH,
          payload: snapshot.val(),
        });
        navigation.navigate('Profile')
      });
  };
};
```

Note : This is not the best method of handling navigations but use a global navigation service to access directly top level navigator. You can learn more about that in [React Navigation Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigating-without-navigation-prop/). But let's use that for now in this example.

So as you can see, when user login is successful, now you are not requesting data after rendering the Profile page but request data even before navigating to the page. So this ensures that profile page is only getting loaded with relevant data and there will be no lag like in your GIF.

Comment: Could you offer more specifics on how exactly I can call fetchProfile() when my user logs in? I don't understand how this translates into passing props to the component.

Comment: @LukeMorrice I modified my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Using firebase you must create a listener.

do something like this:

Reducer Action:

```
// Action Creators
export function onAuthChanged(fb) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    fb.auth().onAuthStateChanged((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: Types.SET_ATTR,
        payload: {
          attr: 'user',
          value: res,
        },
      });
    });
  };
}
```

call this function from a FirebaseProvider componentWillMount function

then

put the FirebaseProvider on your App class;

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <TranslatorProvider />
        <FirebaseProvider />
        <ThemeProvider>
          <TrackingProvider>
            <Routes />
          </TrackingProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
};
```

the listener will save on your reducer the user when it login and logout